# in angular a class is not exporting

Tags: angular

I have

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';   

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
    title = 'LOGIN';
    log = 'j';
}
```

In the app.module.ts I put

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent

  ],
   imports: [
   BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I get a compilation error, claiming that

> "my-app/src/app/login.component" has no exported member 'LoginComponent'

Comment: You add in app.module something like this @NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ]

Comment: could you add here your `app.module.ts` ?